# Packages and dependencies do not upgrade {ubuntu 18.04 LTS}

Tags: ubuntu

i ran the following command in the terminal , still it says 9 packages can be upgraded

> > sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

the minor problem being it states

> > type apt list --upgradable to show packages that can be upgraded..............

i have attached the screenshot stating the problem above

[image]

Comment: The screenshot you provided does not indicate a problem.  `apt update` said there were 9 updates, and `apt upgrade` is in the process of downloading 9 updates.

Comment: UPDATE thanks a lot @Deltik , understood after running the same command it did update the packages